# How to query Google Analytics Reporting for specific directories

Tags: c#, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-analytics-filters

I am generating a Google report. My problem is it only returns the 0th list item from the variable `filter.Expressions`. I'm filling a Google Charts Table with the results.

Any pointers how I could get this to return all 5 list items in `filter.Expressions` so that I get the avgSessionDuration, sessions, pageviewsPerSession for each directory ( "/Brain/", "/Brainhearing/", "/Dementia/", "/Invisible/", "/Tinnitus/" )?

[image: Returned results from list <code>filter.Expressions</code>]

```
//create date range, metrics, dimensions and expresssions.
DateRange dateRange = new DateRange() { StartDate = "30daysAgo", EndDate = "yesterday" };
Metric sessions = new Metric { Expression = "ga:sessions", Alias = "Sessions" };
Dimension landingPagePath = new Dimension { Name = "ga:landingPagePath" };    
var filterClause = new DimensionFilterClause();
var filter = new DimensionFilter
{
    DimensionName = "ga:landingPagePath",
    Operator__ = "PARTIAL",
    Expressions = new List<string> { "/Brain/", "/Brainhearing/", "/Dementia/", "/Invisible/", "/Tinnitus/" }
};

filterClause.Filters = new List<DimensionFilter> { filter };

// Create the ReportRequest object.
ReportRequest reportRequestLandingPath = new ReportRequest
{
    ViewId = GoogleAnalyticsIds,
    DateRanges = new List<DateRange>() { dateRange },
    Dimensions = new List<Dimension>() { landingPagePath },
    Metrics = new List<Metric>() { avgSessionDuration, sessions, pageviewsPerSession },
    DimensionFilterClauses = new List<DimensionFilterClause> { filterClause }
};

List<ReportRequest> requests = new List<ReportRequest>();
    requests.Add(reportRequestLandingPath);

// Create the GetReportsRequest object.
GetReportsRequest getReport = new GetReportsRequest() { ReportRequests = requests };

// Call the batchGet method.
var batchRequest = GetAnalyticsReportingService().Reports.BatchGet(getReport);
GetGoogleReport = batchRequest.Execute();
```

Comment: Google analytics does not have directories so i dont understand your question.

Comment: I could be wrong with my definition of a directory. Domain.com/ThisDirectory is what I'm referring to. specifically with my question is MyDomain.com/Brain, MyDomain.com/Brainhearing, MyDomain.com/Dementia...etc.. My code only returns /Brain. I need it to return all the list items instead of just the 0th item in my variable 'Expressions'. @DaImTo